# Custom List View in android is not working. App stops working. Image view is not showing images

Tags: android, android-imageview, listadapter

I am new to android studio, trying to learn it. I was trying to make a list view with custom adapter to show image and text. But it stops working. I tried everything on internet but didn't work.I have figured out that error is in public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) method at line ImageView.setImageResource (R.drawable.ic_launcher); But I am struggling to solve it. Please help.`

```
public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final Activity context;
private final String[] ProgName;
private final Integer[] ProgImages;

public MyListAdapter(Activity context, String[] progName, Integer[] progImages) {
    super(context,R.layout.activity_image_list,progName);
    this.context = context;
    this.ProgName = progName;
    this.ProgImages = progImages;

}

    public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent){


    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater ();
    View rowView=inflater.inflate (R.layout.activity_image_list,null,true);
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView)rowView.findViewById (R.id.txtName);
    ImageView ImageView = (ImageView)rowView.findViewById (R.id.ImageList1);

    ImageView.setImageResource (ProgImages[position]);
    txtTitle.setText ((ProgName[position]));

    ImageView.setImageResource (R.drawable.ic_launcher);


    return rowView;
    }

MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView list;
Context context;
ArrayList Prglist;
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

public static Integer[] ProgImages = {
        R.drawable.ic_launcher1, 
R.drawable.ic_launcher1,R.drawable.ic_launcher1,
R.drawable.ic_launcher1
};

public static String[] ProgName = {
        "Java", "C", "Pascal", "Python"
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
    setContentView (R.layout.activity_main);
    MyListAdapter adapter=new MyListAdapter(this, ProgName, ProgImages);

    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

If ProgImages array is resource(like R.drawable.icon), you can use getResources method. Try this;

in Activity;

```
ImageView.setImageResource(getResources(ProgImages[position]));
```

in Fragment;

```
ImageView.setImageResource(getActivity().getResources(ProgImages[position]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use photo libraries like picasso or glide to view your images.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have used the Drawable image in an imageview.
Maybe try this...

```
imgView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
```

or you can use Picasso or Glide Library for better performance...